# IMagick for PHP 5.4 x64

Tags: php, imagick

I have PHP 5.4.3 (x64, TS, VC9) installed and I need to use IMagick.

I got installed ImageMagick 6.8.3, then 6.6.2, after I read that all higher are compiled with VC10.

I tried a lot of DLL's, for example this: http://valokuva.org/?page_id=50, but every time I include php_imagick.dll in php.ini error is the same:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:  in Unknown on line 0

Please, help me find an appropriate DLL or tell me how to compile it and which version it should be (PECL sources)?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the PHP folder to the path and restarting the computer.

If that doesn't make sense to you, see this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable
under PATH